# How add custom CSS code to wp_head if current_time is between A and B?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a style to an element if the current time is between 12:00 am and 3:00 am. I figured I can add the style snippet in the header to override parent and child stylesheets. However, I can't figure out how to add the time parameters.

I'm familiar with how to hook a function to wp_head and how to display the custom CSS, and I have read about current_time and how to build an IF statement. You can check my code below.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'time_based_style');

function time_based_style() {
    $now = current_time( 'mysql' );
    $begintime = date('???');
    $endtime = date('???');
    if($now >= $begintime && $now <= $endtime){
        ?>
            <style>
            ...
            </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

How do I format the date objects so that the IF statement will be like if current time is between 12:00 am and 3:00 am, then print style?

Comment: You should include date time both in comparison if this you want for today only not for past or future dates. And your code seems okay except the above mentioned case.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'time_based_style');

function time_based_style() {
    $now = current_time( 'mysql' );
    $begintime = date('00:00:00');
    $endtime = date('03:00:00');
    if($now >= $begintime && $now <= $endtime){
        ?>
            <style>
            ...
            </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I figured that I needed to format the time like how 'mysql' is formatted (HH:MM:SS). Since I would like the function to execute everyday, I didn't include the dates and just entered the times.